# Extracting URL and error message from images

Tags: python, ocr

I need to extract the URL and error message from the images.  The DPI of the image is 300 and size is W 1536 Pixels H 1068 Pixels.

```
import glob
list_f = glob.glob('/home/agnihotri/img/*.jpg')
if len(list_f) != 0:
     res_final = []
     for f in list_f:

          from PIL import Image
          import pytesseract
          import argparse
          import cv2
          import os, glob
          from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
          import re

          if not os.path.exists('processed/images'):
              os.makedirs('processed/images')

          image = cv2.imread(f)
          if image.shape[0]< 715 or image.shape[1]<1020:
              print('Resolution too low')
          else:
              image = cv2.resize(image, None, fx = 10, fy = 10)
              config='-c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ:.// -psm 3'

              text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, config=config, nice=2)
          try:
              url = (''.join(
                   re.findall('(http|ftp|https):(//|H)([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?',
                               text)[0]).replace('H', '://').replace('::', ':').replace('I', '/').replace('BBBB', '8888'))
           except:
               url = 'No url found in image'
               print(url)

           err_message = []
           for l in text.split(sep='\n'):
               if any(i in l.lower() for i in ['error', 'cannot', 'warning', 'problem', "can't", 'unable', 'could not', 'invalid']):

                    err_message.append(l)

           if len(err_message) == 0:
               err_message=['No error message found']
           err_message = '\n'.join(err_message)
           print (err_message)
```

However, i do get the error message after executing above mentioned code:

```
No url found in image
Traceback (most recent call last): File "./oc_script.py", line 37, in <module>
TypeError: split() takes no keyword arguments
```

Link for the input image is https://drive.google.com/open?id=1drdqJjR06EIkt_YbBcVLDZW1s8FRj1J6

Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
for l in text.split(sep='\n'):
```

to

```
for l in text.split(r'\n'):
```

Comment: Thanks it works.  However, this is how it extracts the url from the image:  AddreSs a https:Nahalya.ad.infosys.comz8888ISSOIuifSSOLogin.html

Comment: instead it should AddreSs a https://ahalya.ad.infosys.com:8888/SSO/ui/SSOLogin.html

Comment: any suggestions how do i handle this